# How can I set the value of a Field() that is not being populated by Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a script in which not all values need to be scraped from a website. The reason I am doing it this way is because I need an export sheet that has specific fields.

I have these fields,

```
class Post(Item):
    head = Field()
    links = Field()
    url = Field()
```

the `url = Field()` I want to set a value to myself. I understand that Field() in Scrapy is just a Python dict but I am unsure as to how to go about updating this since my other items (head and links) also use `Field()`.

I am using `sel.xpath` for the other items,

```
item ["head"] = sel.xpath("my-x-path").extract()[0].strip()
item ["links"] = sel.xpath("my-x-path").extract()[0].strip()
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't use `item["url"] = "my value"`, or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I tried that but I get this error `return item` `IndentationError: unexpected indent` which is odd considering `return item` never moved.

Comment: That's a completely different error, check your indentation, watch tabs and spaces.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I'm having, as soon as I remove the `item["url"] = "my value"` the error goes away... I'm not adding any tabs, spaces, etc. I'll try again, typing it out char by char.

Comment: Check the lines above it. You may be missing a `) } ] or :` somewhere along the way and the interpreter gives you the error on the line that you are having a problem with.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that somewhere, in the beginning, I got sloppy and in the midst of copying/pasting/backspacing I must have carried over something extra. I just typed out the whole script again, line by line and it works.